# Disable validation controls based on a condition

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I have an asp.net application that uses validation controls on textboxes. However, if the user enters a value in txtFieldA, then I want to disable the validation controls on txtFieldB and txtFieldC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use this JavaScript function

```
function Disable()
{
  var myVal = document.getElementById('myValidatorClientID');
  ValidatorEnable(myVal, false);  
}
```

Comment: where would I call the Disable function?

Comment: you can use textbox onblur event and you need to call this on txtFieldA

Answer (score 0):

Override `Page.Validate()` or `Page.Validate(string)` to change the default validation policy.